# Drop all rows that contain any string from a dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains strings in columns that should be only floats. I saw several solutions on how to drop a row with a specific string or parts of it from an individual column.

So for an individual column I suppose one could do it like this

`new_df = df[df['Column'].dtypes != object]`

But this

`new_df = df[df.dtypes != object]`

did not work. One could iterate over all columns via a loop, but is there a way to drop the strings for all columns at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
#excluding object columns
new_df = df.select_dtypes(exclude=object)
```

---

```
#only floats columns
new_df = df.select_dtypes(include=float)
```

---

```
#only numeric columns
new_df = df.select_dtypes(include=np.number)
```

EDIT:

```
new_df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').dropna()
```

Comment: When you say `excluding object columns` do you mean it will remove the entire column that contains a string?
I would only like to remove some rows

Comment: @lpnorm - are missing values in original data?

Comment: There are multiple columns where instead of an empty entry or a nan there is e.g. `'?'`. If the values were missing I would have dropped the rows with `df.dropna()`.

Comment: @lpnorm - Can you try `new_df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').dropna()` ?